# How to pass sensitive data to Google Cloud Endpoints from Android app?

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to create a simple minimal session management kind of system in Google Endpoints.

I authenticate users on my Android app. For making authenticated Endpoint API calls, I plan to verify the user only once on the Endpoint server by passing the `idToken` in the first call to Endpoints API from Android app.

I would, then, assign a `session_id` (say  a number) to that user. This `session_id` would be communicated back to that Android app. The Cloud Endpoint server would not verify the user for the next 24 hours.

When an Android app calls an endpoints API with that `session_id`, I would perform the required operations assuming it to be from the authenticated user.

**CONCERNS**
If anyone sniffs the `session_id`, he would be able to perform operations of an authenticated user.

**Q 1** 
Is it secure ( and correct way) to pass sensitive data (like `session_id`) to Google Cloud Endpoints from Android app ?

**Q 2** 
Is all communication between Android app and Cloud Endpoints done via HTTPS by default even though I do not have HTTPS enabled for my website ? 
[Official doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/) says :

> Important: Google Cloud Endpoints requires SSL. If you need to access
>   your backend API in a system not supporting SSL, you'll need to either
>   update the system to support SSL or use a proxy.

Another [Official doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api) says:

> In both method decorators, we supply the path to specify a location at
>   which the method serves requests. The value specified is appended to
>   the API path, for example, if the value hellogreeting is specified,
>   the path is
>   https://your-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/helloworld/v1/hellogreeting.
>   For greetings.getGreeting, the path is hellogreeting/{id} where {id}
>   is required or else your API method won't receive the incoming request
>   argument.

NOTE: 
I do not have SSL (HTTPS) enabled for my website. I use GAE Python on web and Android/Java. I have website and an Android app which I am migrating from Google authentication to [Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/) based multiple provider authentication (like Facebook, Google, others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1**. It can be assumed to be secure (from sniffing) if it's passed via HTTPS only, although I am not sure if it's the correct way which depends on your implementation. You mentioned it would be a number. What kind of a number? Randomly generated? Sequential?

Also, are you using Users API / webapp2? I like the built-in [`create_auth_token`](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.html) function which can save you some time and replace the `session_id` in your case, and then you could use `get_by_auth_token` or `validate_token` to get corresponding user or simply validate the token and `delete_auth_token` to invalidate the token.

If you are not using Users API / webapp2 it's still better if you don't use random or sequential numbers for tokens, instead  something like [`token = HMAC('A_VERY_LONG_AND_SECRET_KEY', user_id + todays_date)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), which is unique, valid for 24 hours (from midnight, NOT since creation time) and is secret as long as the key is secret is a much better and safer option.

**Q2**. Even if your custom domain does not have an SSL certificate, your APPID.appspot.com does (try accessing your project via **`httpS://`** and you'll see).

Cloud Endpoints is ALWAYS serving the APIs via SSL (there's actually no way of changing it).

The warning Google gives you is about a possible situation when a CLIENT does not support SSL connections which won't be happening very often in real world.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure if it is a bad idea but I am thinking of using `sequential numbers` if the communication, between Android and Could Endpoints, is HTTPS. If it is not, then irrespective of whatever I use, there is very less security. 
You are right about the `https: //mydomain.appspot.com` being HTTPS. But i do not know `where to provide this HTTPS URL in Android app or Could Endpoint so that this URL is used for all communication`. 
I suspect this URL might be used by Endpoints only during Google account based authentication but am not sure.

Comment: Also, I cannot use Users API now since I am migrating to Google Identity Toolkit based authentication.

Comment: Sequential numbers might be a bad idea for two reasons: 1) even if you use HTTPS everywhere, your `token` / `session_id` won't be sniffable, but the end user still can find out what it is and eventually figure out that incrementing it will open access to next user's data. 2) it's not easy to implement a sequential ID in NDB. Also, take a look at my **Q2** update regarding Endpoints/SSL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information that all Endpoint to Android app communication is always HTTPS. I think I could now safely assume that the data exchanged between my Android app and the Cloud Endpoint server could not be sniffed by anyone. As per your suggestion, I would try to use random numbers instead of sequential ones for session_id.

Comment: I did not suggest you using random numbers... :) Unless it's a truly random 64 bit `int` (`long` in python2.7) that's also not the best way to go (it still could be bruteforced if you have many users, but it is a little better than using a sequential number). I added another update to the answer above which I think is a better solution. Another good point of the **HMAC** suggestion is that you don't have to store the generated token on the server side at all, just validate on incoming requests since it will be same for the same user the whole 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks Mihail R for your suggestion. I would explore that and would try to use something like HMAC.